# Not able to programmatically load files from bundle to UITextView and UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I've been trying to load images and text files from the main bundle into UITextView and UIImageView boxes. I have connected the outlets properly from the .xib file and have ensured the files I am trying to load are present in the bundle, but they are not loading, and when I test them through NSLog they come back as null. Copied below is code from the .h and .m files. In case you were wondering, some of the outlets are strong, because I've just been trying to mess with the settings to get it to work, so far to no avail.

".h file"

```
@interface CluesViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cluesBackground;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *titleImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *typeATitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *typeBTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *divider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *typeAText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *typeBText;

-(void)updateCluesViewInfoTypeA:(NSString *)typeA updateCluesViewInfoTypeB:(NSString *)typeB;

@end
```

".m file"

```
-(void)updateCluesViewInfoTypeA:(NSString *)typeA updateCluesViewInfoTypeB:(NSString *)typeB {

    NSString *bGImageString = NULL;
    bGImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@-bg", typeA, typeB];
    NSString *bGPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:bGImageString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *bGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:bGPath];
    [_cluesBackground setImage:bGImage];

    NSString *titleImageString = NULL;
    titleImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@-clues", typeA, typeB];
    NSString *titleImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:titleImageString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:titleImagePath];
    [_titleImage setImage:titleImage];

    NSString *typeATitleImageString = NULL;
    typeATitleImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-text", typeA];
    NSString *typeATitlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:typeATitleImageString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *typeATitleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:typeATitlePath];
    [_typeATitle setImage:typeATitleImage];

    NSString *typeBTitleImageString = NULL;
    typeBTitleImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-text", typeB];
    NSString *typeBTitlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:typeBTitleImageString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *typeBTitleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:typeBTitlePath];
    [_typeBTitle setImage:typeBTitleImage];

    NSString *dividerImageString = NULL;
    dividerImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@-divider", typeA, typeB];
    NSString *dividerImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dividerImageString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *dividerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:dividerImagePath];
    [_divider setImage:dividerImage];

    NSString *typeATextString = NULL;
    typeATextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Clues", typeA];
    NSString *typeATextPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:typeATextString ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* typeATextContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:typeATextPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    self.typeAText.text = typeATextContent;

    NSString *typeBTextString = NULL;
    typeBTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Clues", typeB];
    NSString *typeBTextPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:typeBTextString ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* typeBTextContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:typeBTextPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    self.typeBText.text = typeBTextContent;

    NSLog(@"The textfield is %@", self.typeBText.text);
}
```

Comment: When is the `updateCluesViewInfoTypeA:updateCluesViewInfoTypeB:` called? It must be called after `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: It is called after viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `imageNamed:` incorrectly. You should just pass in the image name:

```
NSString *bGImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@-bg", typeA, typeB];
UIImage *bGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:bGImageString];
```

Make this change for the other images as well. You only want to use the full path of the image with `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:`, not `imageNamed:`.

As for the files, are you sure the file encoding is ASCII and not UTF-8?

If the encoding isn't the problem then use the `error` parameter to see what the problem is.

```
NSString *typeATextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Clues", typeA];
NSString *typeATextPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:typeATextString ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* typeATextContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:typeATextPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
if (typeATextContent) {
    self.typeAText.text = typeATextContent;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to load text from %@: %@", typeATextPath, error);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the code you suggested, but the error comes back as null as well. Also I checked the typeATextContent variable and it is loaded with the text file I intended.

Comment: If `typeATextContent` has the correct value then that is good. If the text doesn't appear in the text view then that means that `self.typeAText` is `nil`. Your outlet must not be connected properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the outlets by `nonatomic`,like...

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *typeBText;
```

Comment: Why should that help? The code he uses is the one generated by Xcode and works.